# iOS Swift - Execute function if current date is equal to number of this month

Tags: ios, swift, string, date, formatting

I have a string containing the default Date(), which looks like this:

```
"2017-05-10 20:34:18 +0000"
```

How do I run a function if the number of this month is the same as the string? (In this case, the number of the month should be 5)

I'm thinking it could look something like this:

```
let CurrentMonth = 5 // This number should be the number of the current month
let StringsMonth = 5 // This number should be grabbed from the string shown above.

if StringsMonth == CurrentMonth {
   print("WORKS!")
}
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you get month

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
```

This is how you convert your timestamp and get month

```
let datestring = "2017-05-10 20:34:18 +0000"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ"
let date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: datestring)
let month2 = calendar.component(.month, from: date2!)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let date = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current

let StringsMonth = 5 
let CurrentMonth = calendar.component(.month, from: date)

if StringsMonth == CurrentMonth {
   print("WORKS!")
}
```